# How to debug a chrome extension and its native host?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome-extension, remote-debugging, chrome-native-messaging

I have a Java program as my [native messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), and I have a Chrome extension.

The native app and the extension communicate using [native messaging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol). In native messaging the host app reads from/write to the standard input and output. The host app is started by Chrome from the extension code.

I want to debug my Java code. How can I attach to Eclipse after e.g. a message is sent to Java program (which is my host) by the extension?

Comment: It would help you to get answers if you describe how native hosts work in this context (i.e. communication protocol and how they are run) in the question itself. Quoting the linked docs can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with same problem. The main cause why debug not working - message("Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005") from debug mode to System.out which crushes native messaging connection.

Solution:

> java
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,**suspend=y**,address=5005,**quiet=y**
> -jar path_to_jarfile.jar

suspend=y - will wait for debug connection before execution

quiet=y - will prevent extra messages from debug mode to System.out